# What could prevent the creation of a gem specification file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, specifications

I tried to update the specs on a gem that didn't have a .specification file.

```
1. cd {application_home_directory}
2. rake gems:refresh_specs
```

When I did, I received the recursive warning:

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem in vendor/gems has no specification file. 
Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
```

I've also tried this, which also fails to create a specification without any error/warning:

```
1. cd vendor/gems/gemname
2. gem specification gemname > .specification
```

**What could prevent the creation of a gem specification file in these cases?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `config.gem` statements for your gems in your environment.rb file? In my experience, you need to have the gems set up in your configuration in order for `rake gems:refresh_specs` to know about them.

Comment: Aargh! Yes, that's right. Want to bang my head against the wall. Thanks.